# How to select value of k in K-NN when using Transfer Entropy?

Tags: r, causality, entropy, k-nearest-neighbour, mutual-information

I was reading about Transfer Entropy and I came across the estimators used to calculate TE, one of them being the Kraskov Estimator:

$ T_{X \rightarrow Y} = \frac{p(Y_{n+1}, Y(k)_{n}, X(l)_{n})*log(Y_{n+1}| Y(k)_{n}, X(l)_{n})}{p(Y_{n+1}|Y(k)_{n})}$

I saw in a video that $k$ should be the square root of the total length of the random variable but if I use that in TE I get a negative value (which is not correct). Although I read in this paper by Kraskov https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0305641.pdf that we should take k between 2 and 4, I didn't get the reason behind it.

Comment: This is an interesting question (+1) but I think you will get a better answer in the Physics.SE or the Theoretical Computer.SE. (Even the paper cited is part of the "Condensed Matter" area of arXiv)

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?  Generally it is helpful to state the question explicitly in the body of your question (not just in the title).  Can you give us some context?  Are you asking about how to estimate TE?  If so, what does this have to do with nearest-neighbors classifiers?  Are you asking how to select the value of k in a k-nearest neighbors classifier?  If so how does TE relate?  What does the notation mean?  What does $Y_n$ and $Y(k)$ represent, etc.?  Can you provide a citation/reference to where you saw that advice about how to choose $k$?

Comment: @D.W.: The suggestion is in the linked paper, page 7, LHS column, bottom lines.

Comment: Unfortunately, moderators at both sites have said this would be off topic there.

Comment: @user11852 thanks for the suggestion I will see if I can get an answer there.